# Iptables: masquarading and routing

Tags: iptables, routing, nat

I have a WAN router which is linked to isp over a `/30` WAN subnet. But it also servers as a router to a `/29` local public WAN subnet which is connected to few of my servers. The traffic from `/29` gets routed to ISP via `/30` subnet.  For a wired reason I want to masqarade (NAT) the interface which has `/30` ip. So the interface with `/30` ip should appear as masquaraded for my `192.168.1.0/24` network and it also should act as a normal non-NAT router for my WAN public subnet `/29`. Can this be done with iptables on a Linux machine?

**EDIT1:**
How my firewall rules are at present:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

#WAN Security
iptables -A INPUT -d 1.2.3.3 -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d 1.2.3.3 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#NAT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.3

#FORWARD
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT


iptables -A INPUT -d 1.2.3.3 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will work just fine. Set up your packet filtering and your routing just like you would if you weren't using any NAT at all and then add something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.3
```

(Assuming that your ISP is connected to eth0, and your public IP is 1.2.3.3.)

This will apply the NAT only to packets coming from your LAN with private IP addresses.

Comment: How would I filter ports on 1.2.3.3 (firewall), without affecting my `/29` subnet?

Comment: Use the -d flag of iptables to filter traffic destined only for 1.2.3.3.

Comment: I have only two interfaces. So `eth0` will be `1.2.3.3/30`. So can I have other one like this: `eth1` `192.168.1.1/24` and `eth1:0` as `1.2.4.77/29`?

Comment: There's no reason I can think of that wouldn't work. But in general I'd recommend against having multiple IP subnets on a single Ethernet network. Even if you have only two physical interfaces on the router, you can still use VLANs to partition your Ethernet network.

Comment: I have updated my question with my final iptables rules. Any suggestions or advice?